# Spring batch define FlatFileItemReader in class reader that implements ItemReader not in bean java conf

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a step where i defined reader, processor and writer.

I want to define for each of them his own class, For the reader to get data from a CSV file:

```
public class Reader implements ItemReader<FlatFileItemReader<PersonneDTO>>, StepExecutionListener{  

    private String file;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        file = (String) stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("personneFile");  
    }

    @Override
    public FlatFileItemReader<PersonneDTO> read()
            throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
         FlatFileItemReader<PersonneDTO> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<PersonneDTO>();
            reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(file));
            reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<PersonneDTO>() {{
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                    setNames(new String[] {"nom", "prenom" ,"dateNaissance" });
                }});
                setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PersonneDTO>() {{
                    setTargetType(PersonneDTO.class);
                }});
            }});
            return reader;
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the config java i have

```
 @Bean
public Step stepTraitementFile() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<PersonneDTO, Personne> chunk(1)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}
@Bean
public Reader reader() {
    return new Reader();
}
```

I have an error in configuration java that tells:

> The method reader(ItemReader) in the type
>   SimpleStepBuilder is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Reader).

All the examples I've seen on the net have the reader set in the config class, any help please!!

Comment: Why? Also what you are trying now doesn't make sense.. Your current setup will disable proper setup of the reader (as you will not get the callbacks you normally get. Why the added layer it doesn't add anything but confusion and complexity...

Comment: I need to use the reader in a separate class because the filename I have from a lestener i updated the code to understand what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of how your file name is generated, but maybe you can use [late binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#late-binding) to solve your issue. Late binding lets you instantiate the a Spring Batch bean later when the required information is available. To use late binding, use the "regular" `FlatFileItemReader` but with "step" scope. Something like:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<PersonneDTO> reader(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['personneFile']}") String pathToDFile) {
     FlatFileItemReader<PersonneDTO> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<PersonneDTO>();
     reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(pathToDFile));
     reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<PersonneDTO>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames(new String[] {"nom", "prenom" ,"dateNaissance" });
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PersonneDTO>() {{
            setTargetType(PersonneDTO.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
  }
```